# Scala slick checking if the DDL table and db schema table have the same shape

Tags: database, scala, orm, schema, slick

Building on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442034/how-could-i-know-if-a-database-table-is-exists-in-scalaquery) question, is there a suite of functions for checking if the shape of code side DDL tables coincides with what is in the DB. I'd like to detect 1) if db types are compatible, and 2)if they are exact matches.

I'd like to do this before my application continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you would have to use Slick internals.

As a hack: You could check existence of all columns by running queries against all tables and columns and see if they throw exceptions.

In 2.0 we add code generation which allows you to stay in sync in that way. We will use a meta model describing the reverse engineered database schema. In Slick 2.1 or later we will add a way to also get the meta model from your Table class. You could check if they match.

Comment: Hi thanks :D I found some references in your videos to this new generator. I have come the conclusion that I should stick to my own DDL (I use lots of postgres' advanced features). Could you perhaps show me some examples of getting the codegen working ? I guess I need to apply my schema file to the db from sbt, and then run the generator plugin. I can't find any documentation for it  though :(

Comment: you need to create an sbt task for running the schema in the db. there is no codegen documentation as we did not release it yet. release should be in 1-2 weeks. docs soon after.